# How to define the feature template in Falcon40B

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, large-language-model, falcon

I am attempting to fine tune a Falcon 40B model in sagemaker, I have created a template in the below format

Original Template:-

````
  "prompt": "question: {Company} context: {Year}",
  "completion": "{Some_Information}"
}```
Oringal Data Format:-
```{"Company":"Ford","Year":"2022","Some_Information":"Some Info 1234"}```

Proposed Data Format:-
```{"Company":"Ford","Year":"2022","Some_Information":"Some_input":"1234","Some_Data":"Data abcd"}```

1)I want to include the additional tags to the completion section, how do I do it?

```Is it "completion": "{Some_Information,Some_Input,Some_Data}"```
 or 
```"completion": "{Some_Information}{Some_Input},{Some_Data}"```
2)I want to pass the array data type to the completion section, how do I do it?
````